# What is the difference between declaring variables with square braces and curly braces in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between declaring variables with square braces and curly braces in AngularJs? 
Example:
$scope.options ={};
$scope.options = [];

What "options" would be called if I declare like above? Is it an empty string or empty array?

Answer (score 2):

{} means it is an object, [] means it is an array. that's very basic in javascript

Answer (score 2):

nothing magical

```
 $scope.options ={}; // declares an object
 $scope.options = []; //declares an array
```

are same as in plain JavaScript

```
var options = {};//declares an object   
var options = []; //declares an array
```

And your option just a property of `$scope`  and it's type depends how it is declared  `{}` or `[]`
`$scope.yourVariable` //This is the way how we declare variable in within scope in angular

That'all

Answer (score 1):

This `$scope.options = {};` declares an object. While this `$scope.options = [];` declares an array.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is for defining `object` .
`[]` is for `array`.

```
$scope.variable = [] //array
$scope.variable = {} //object
```

If you define like above , it will be either empty array or empty object .

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that *AngularJS* is built on top of Javascript and, for this reason, *AngularJS* cannot do anything that *VanillaJS* can't do!

The **=** character is an **assignment operator** in javascript...

So, when you write: `var myVariable = anotherVariable` you are assigning the value of `anotherVariable` to the variable that is **left-hand** to the **operator**.

#### [In javascript `[]` indicates an indexed array and `{}` indicates an associative array...](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

So, as javascript does, when you assign using *curly braces* you are assigning an Associative array to the variable ($scope....), viceversa, using *square braces* you are assigning an indexed array.
Angular doesn't make any difference!

#### In AngularJS the model ($scope in your case) is a [PLAIN OLD JAVASCRIPT OBJECT](https://code.google.com/p/shhbox/wiki/POJO), so there are no differences with VanillaJS.